# How to debug a mozilla based binary application ?

Tags: linux, gdb, mozilla

Komodo Edit crashed on my system , and i tried to debug it , added '-g' option inside komodo script,

And i got:

[New Thread 0xa80c2b70 (LWP 5102)]
[New Thread 0xa78c1b70 (LWP 5107)]

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xa97e1f10 in ?? () from /usr/lib/librsvg-2.so.2
(gdb) bt
#0  0xa97e1f10 in ?? () from /usr/lib/librsvg-2.so.2
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Operation not permitted
```

Is there any way to find out the real problem here ?
I wanted to know where that last string 'Operation not permitted' come from , but how ?
Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> added '-g' option inside komodo script,

When you say this, do you mean that you passed `-g` as a command-line argument?

If so, that won't work. `-g` (or `-ggdb`) needs to be passed to `gcc`, during compilation of Komodo Edit, so that debugging symbols are included in the output.

Comment: passing -g will start a gdb instance to debug komodo-bin program , it's a parameter of run-mozilla.sh script

Comment: You still need to compile komodo with debugging symbols.